# merging two or more revisions

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

In tortoise svn, is it possible to merge two revisions within the trunk (not two branches)?
![alt text][1]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159911/

Answer (score 1):

In svn, you merge *changes* to a working copy; a revision represents a static tree. You can certainly use svn merge to apply the change between two revisions onto your working copy.

In fact, svn doesn't really know about trunks or branches at all - branches are just a convention of looking at copies-with-history as a branch.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with this.

If the svn client you are using is giving you an error you could always branch from the revision you want to merge in then use that branch.